# Can't ping server over VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I can RDC to a remote server over VPN, but ping requests time out. It's Windows 2008 R2, is this a new security feature?

Comment: What VPN software are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a firewall rule allowing ICMP from your VPN to your inside network.

Comment: Actually alolow it. Simple switch with normal firewall, a rule under FILE AND PRINTER rules (!) in the adcvanced firewall. off by default. First rule I did put into Group Policies - turn that ON and allow ICMP.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the combination of the VPN being used, its configuration as well as possible corresponding configurations behind the VPN server/client, that might be "normal" or configured behavior.

Has ping/ICMP worked with the subject configuration in the past?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your firewall settings?